# Android: Market-like swypable or scollable tabs

Tags: android, google-play, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I always wanted to implement "swypable" tabs in my application, like the ones in the Market app by Google.
I found many libraries and [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) by android-developers.
But after reading [this-brand-new-page](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) by Google (yesterday) my question is... is there a better way (maybe a new implementation in the newest API) to implement this layout? (they call this "Scrollable tabs")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is still no way in the API to implement tabs similar to those on the Market. I've been longing for an API solution, too, especially since the new design docs promote the use of the pattern.

In the meantime, try using [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). It's made by the same developer of ActionBarSherlock, and is about as easy to use.